# Form in ajax post method sends empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webform with several fields I want to capture in an object and send it to a controller method. The form has this code:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("NuevaOpcion", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frm_nueva_opcion" })) {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: .7em;margin-top: .7em;">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button" onclick=" $('#row-nueva-opcion').toggle()" id="add-opcion">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> A&ntilde;adir nueva opci&oacute;n
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row-nueva-opcion" style="display:none">
                    <div class="col-md-10">

                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="opcion-extra" onclick=" $('#nuevo-precio').attr('disabled', !this.checked);" />
                            Es opci&oacute;n extra
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:1.7em;">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Opción" class="form-control" name="nombre" style="max-width:70%;">
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Cantidad" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" name="cantidad" style="max-width:15%;">
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Precio" class="form-control" id="nuevo-precio" name="precio" style="max-width:15%;" disabled>
                            <input type="hidden" name="idrespuesta"  id="idrespuesta" value="@listItems.Select(x=>x.Value).FirstOrDefault()" />
                            <div class="input-group-addon">&euro;</div>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-title="Confirmación de acción" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_confirm" onclick="confirmar('frm_nueva_opcion')">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Guardar
                                </a>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>
                                ¿Para que pregunta es la opción?
                                @Html.DropDownList("OptionSelectedItem", listItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

To manage it, I have a script that looks like this:

```
function mostrarModal(idmodal, mensaje, tipo) {
$(idmodal + ' .modal-body h4').addClass(tipo == 'error' ? 'text-danger' : 'text-secondary').html(mensaje);
$(idmodal).modal('show');
}

function enviar(form) {
debugger;
var NuevoPrecio = $('#' + form).attr("nuevo-precio");
if( (NuevoPrecio == null) || (typeof NuevoPrecio === "undefined") ) { var NuevoPrecio = 0; }
var datos = {
    Id: $('#' + form).attr("#Id"),
    IdPresupuestador: $('#' + form).attr("#idPresupuestador"),
    IdRespuesta: $('#' + form).attr("#idrespuesta"),
    Cantidad: $('#' + form).attr("#cantidad"),
    Nombre: $('#' + form).attr("#nombre"),
    Precio: NuevoPrecio,
}
$.post("NuevaOpcion", {
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(datos),
});
}

var modalConfirm = function (callback) {
$("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function () {
    callback(true);
    $("#modal-confirm").modal('hide');
});
$("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function () {
    callback(false);
    $("#modal-confirm").modal('hide');
}); };

function confirmar(form, text) {
$("#modal-confirm").modal('show');
modalConfirm(function (confirm) {
    if (confirm) {
        enviar(form);
    }
}); };
```

Trouble is, I've changed the script on several points and now looks like this because the best I could manage was taking all the form in a single object. I can't work with the properties contained in that object, not on the script and neither on the controller method.

So, the question is, how am I selecting the fields wrong? I've tried with "#", ".", just the name between quotes, and as I said, the best I could get was the entire form in a single object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this function can help you. [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) P.s. you can take the value from one input field like this $('#idrespuesta').val();

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thanks for your comment. Where do you suggest I use serialize? I've tried that selection, got undefined. Thanks again.

Comment: But in your controller you don't receive the post data? Try this mode $.post( "yourcontroller.php", $( "#idform" ).serialize() );

Comment: @Sfili_81 I receive an empty object. I'm following the script execution and when I try to set the values from the form, they all get 'undefined'. I'm working with `serialize()` now. Looks promising. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Tried your suggestion, still getting an empty object. I honestly don't know what's wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Do you get some error in your browser console?

Comment: @Sfili_81 No, nothing, I have to check the answer through debug console and the error I'm getting is from my controller's method, not JS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179384/discussion-between-sfili-81-and-dcarmal).